# Generalizing line with angle rules in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, simplify, generalization, angles

I'm looking for an automatic way to generalize/simplify vector lines in QGIS like the following picture :

[image: exemple]

I would like the generalization to include only the angles indicated by the small star on the right. Is that possible with the `v.generalize` tool?

Answer (score 2):

A solution that comes close to what you want, even though not with 100% accurarcy (see at the end of this answer why and how to correct this):

1. Explode the line to get each segment as a separate feature
2. On the exploded layer, create a new field `azimuth` with field calculator using this expression - it returns the angle of the :

   `degrees ( azimuth( start_point( $geometry), end_point( $geometry)))`
3. Create a field `rounded` to round the azimuth to mulitples of 45 [degrees]:

   `if ( azim%45 < (45/2), azim- azim%45, azim +(45-azim%45))`
4. Now create a new line with `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression`, centered at the centroid of each (exploded) line-segment with the rounded azimuth and extend it for such a distance that the lines intersect (change the two values of `100` at the end of the expression so that the lines clearly intersect) - see screenshot below:

```
   extend (
    with_variable (
        'line',
        make_line (
            start_point ($geometry),
            project (
                start_point ($geometry), 
                length (
                    make_line (
                        start_point($geometry), 
                        end_point ($geometry)
                    )
                ),
            radians ("rounded" )
            )
        ),
        translate (
            @line,
            x ($geometry) - x (centroid (@line)), 
            y ($geometry) - y (centroid (@line)) 
        )
    ),
    100, 100
)
```

*Red: original line; black: lines created in step 4, here with geometry generator:*

[image]

5. `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Line intersections` to get the points where the lines from step 4 intersect
6. Create a new point layer by selecting for each (exploded) line segment the point closest to it from the points of step 5 with `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression` and the following expression and the exploded line as input (change `intersecting_points` to the name of the layer with the result from step 5):

```
array_first ( 
    overlay_nearest( 
        'intersecting_points',
        $geometry
    )
)
```

7. Now use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Points to path` to connect the points from step 6 to a line:

*Red: original line, blue: created line:*
[image]

Why this solution is not 100% accurate (and how to correct this): Easiest to explain is the have a look at the screenshot: the solution is based on creating lines in degrees of multiples of 45 degrees that pass through the centroid of each line segment. Getting the intersecting points, the solution is to connect these connecting points - but only along the created lines.

However, I did not find an easy way to do this - using some network algorithm might help - or manually selecting the points. As you see, the line goes from point 112 (bottom left) directly to 101 (top right), thus here it does not follow the line. Following the line (and thus respecting the 45-degrees rule), the best solution (nearest to the original line) here would be: `112 - 153 - 100 - 101`.

[image]

Maybe someone can elaborate on this.